# Elastic Beanstalk environment stuck in invalid state with "resource(s) failed to update: [AWSEBAutoScalingGroup]"

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

I'm in a catch-22: I cannot change the configuration of my Elastic Beanstalk environment because it is not in a "READY" state and I cannot put it in a ready state without changing the configuration.

The short story is I naively changed the instance type to one that can only be used in a VPC, now the auto scaling group cannot launch the instance, so the auto scale group fails to update, the environment also cannot rollback, so the environment is in an invalid state. And... I cannot change the instance type back until the environment is in a valid state.

**Details:**

In recent events I have

```
2018-11-11 12:48:33 UTC+0100 ERROR Rollback of environment ____ failed. Reason: The following resource(s) failed to update: [AWSEBAutoScalingGroup].
2018-11-11 12:48:33 UTC+0100 ERROR Updating Auto Scaling group named: awseb-e-cpids______-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-______ failed Reason: The specified instance type can only be used in a VPC. A subnet ID or network interface ID is required to carry out the request. Launching EC2 instance failed.
```

Given the above errors I go to configuration of my Elastic Beanstalk environment and click "modify" in the instances square. Then I select a new instance type and click "Apply" at the bottom of the page. I then receive the error

```
Invalid Parameter Value
Environment named _____ is in an invalid state for this operation. Must be Ready.
```

If I go look at the activity history of the auto scaling group I see it is trying to restart the instance every half hour (for the last couple days).

Comment: I ended up delete the environment and recreated it. The above problem happens regularly when changing settings and a setting is invalid. I'm now in the habit of terminating and recreating environments, but it would still be nice to know the answer to this questions.